# Is there a thesaurus for homonyms?

Tags: english

I was considering building some dnd puzzles based on [homonyms](http://www.magickeys.com/books/riddles/words.html) (it took me awhile to discover the correct term). I was both surprised and not that there were already riddles/puzzles based on this theme, but searching "buzzy bee riddles" just gave me children's stuff.

I was hoping that there was some tool that would work much like a dictionary or thesaurus where you enter in the chosen word and are able to see a list of words that sound like it (for example [bare and bear](https://www.teachingtreasures.com.au/teaching-tools/Basic-worksheets/worksheets-english/upper/homophones-list.htm)). Not surprising when I search for homonyms with dictionary and thesaurus I get definitions or other words like it.

Comment: It sounds like you’re interested in ‘homophones’, which is one of the (ambiguous) meanings of ‘homonym’. So, you might try both terms when searching for lists. For example, I found this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_dialect-independent_homophones

Comment: @JeremyNeedle Yes, something like that, however I had hoped there would be more and also able to just do an easy search, but its a start, thank you